# How to add separator between icon and text within button?

Tags: android, android-layout

As question do anyone knows how to add a separator between icon and text of a button?. Check out the demo image below. Thanks in advance

[image]

**EDIT : ANSWER**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_whatever" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AAFFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign up with Facebook"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1E90FF"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.007"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF8C00"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="Sign Up with Facebook"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Even this is cool idea. Which will be consuming minimum cost this XML idea or creating button background separately as Andy suggested??

Comment: I take my words back. When I checked previous one with different screens, your answer is more accurate. It is providing more flexibility. Thanks. I will update the answer for more accurate one. Give some time

Answer (score 2):

You can create a button background with separator.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but what I do is add a View to my layout.xml. In this case the view would have height of matchparent and width of 1 or 2 dp. Then give it an appropriate background color.